# How can I migrate from CruiseControl.Net To Atlassian Bamboo?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, bamboo, continuous-deployment, build-system

I am thinking of making a move from our homegrown CI/CD system to Bamboo + jira.
We are a .Net shop and so the tools need to support the execution of msbuild/msdeploy executables as well the running of .bat and .ps1 files.

What I am looking for is a more complete Agent system for controlling remote machines.
As of now what I do is use a series of powershell scripts and the eventlog in order to coordinate and control deployment on remote machines.

What I am looking for are documents concerning Bamboo in a Windows and .Net environment and how to configure the remote agents to run our deployment scripts.

Comment: ccnet is a CI system, jira is a bug tracker, how can you migrate one to the other?

Comment: Meant to say the bamboo component of jira.

Answer (score 2):

Disclosure: I work for Atlassian on Bamboo and worked on the .NET support.

To execute scripts using Bamboo take a look at our [Script Task](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO/Script). The Script task can run .bat and .exe files.

As mentioned by Francis, Bamboo ships with .NET support. We completely rewrote it in our most recent release (3.1).

We provide Build Tasks for MSTest, MSBuild, Visual Studio and NAnt including test parsing and reporting support for NUnit.

If you have any questions specifically about Bamboo we have a [support forum](http://answers.atlassian.com) which the team monitors for questions daily.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to look at Bamboo - the continuous integration server of Atlassian.
Have a look at the main documentation
http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO/Bamboo+Documentation

and specifically the Bamboo .net plugin 
https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugin/details/5534
if it suits your needs.

(As you might expect Bamboo does integrate neatly with JIRA.)

You might also be interested in the visual studio connector
http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/IDEPLUGIN/Atlassian+Connector+for+Visual+Studio

Hope this helps,

Francis

Answer (score 0):

.ps1 files can be edited and run by [PowerShell Task](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.stellarity.bamboo.powershell-task) for Bamboo.

Disclosure: I am developing it.